# Jump to and display the next object in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been avoiding posting something on here because I was determined to work it out myself, but I have hit a wall.

I have only really been working with jQuery / Javascript for a short amount of time, and in small capacities (basic animation and so on) and I set myself a challenge (and help myself learn) to convert my rather boring portfolio website into a basic "point and click" or text(ish) based game to display my illustrations in a more interactive / creative way.

Anyway - to the point.

I have constructed an array of objects with information about the different areas, and what i was hoping to do is associate either a direction (north, south) with each area based on the the area information.

The Array:

```
var areas = { 

"outskirts" : {
"name" : "Dead city Outskirts",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/outskirts.jpg",

},
"path" : {
"name" : "A lonely Path",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/path.jpg"
},
"cliff" : {
"name" : "An Ultimatum",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image": "images/cliff.jpg"

},
"city" : {
"name" : "Carcass of a City",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/city.jpg"
},
"building" : {
"name" : "Once a home",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/city.jpg"

}
};
```

so for instance,

you start in the outskirts and get information saying that you can move north
and you either type or click an item that says "north" and then it switches to the next area which is "path".

and then populate all of the information based around Path, (name and info and so on)

I thought if I added "exits" to the objects such as:

"exits" : {
   "north" : "path",
   "south" : "cliff"
   },

this could be the key I guess to what directions you could travel, or possibly a true or false statement based on the directions for each area.

So really what I am asking is :

How to do I Move between each area? (change from outskirts.name to path.name)
Am I going down the right road? (My problems could come from inexperience)

I thank anyone that can suggest a solution in advance, and any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The way your designing is quite simple and will work for limited situations.
E.g. you can only specify one city per node for north. What happens if two cities are north of city A.

Except for this though, it is doable.
So, when you click on Building-North, you could access

```
areas[areas[["building"]]["north"]]["name"]
```

There would have to be checks though to make sure values are not undefined.

```
var areas = { 

"outskirts" : {
"name" : "Dead city Outskirts",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/outskirts.jpg",

},
"path" : {
"name" : "A lonely Path",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/path.jpg"
},
"cliff" : {
"name" : "An Ultimatum",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image": "images/cliff.jpg"

},
"city" : {
"name" : "Carcass of a City",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/city.jpg"
},
"building" : {
"name" : "Once a home",
"info" : "What you see around you",
"image" : "images/city.jpg",
"north" : "city"
}
};
alert("JSON.newPrice:"+areas[areas[["building"]]["north"]]["name"]);
```

Comment: myobject.["key"] is not valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Yeh, typos have been fixed.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to Answer, I am still working on trying to get something happening, I will give you a heads up when I get a solution, - Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Say you're at the cliff and you click on the "go north" button. The code that executes could look like this:

```
var curLocationName = "cliff";
var direction = "north";

// Get our new location
var newLocationName = areas[curLocationName].exits[direction];

if(newLocationName === undefined) {
   console.log("You can't go that way!");
} else {
   console.log("You just went to the " + newLocationName);
}

var newLocation = areas[newLocationName];
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for spending the time to reply with an answer, it is greatly appreciated, I do have to ask - is there a way that I can use

    var curLocationName = areas.[nameoftheSubpath] 

I have the areas information coming in from a Json document so I can keep it all modular (just in case I want to add to it later on) and I was hoping to pull the object name "cliff" or "building" in from the Json document, (I really don't know if I am making sense) 

Yet again any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to do something like this:

```
var area = areas['building']; // starting point

do {

   showCurrentArea(area)

   var direction = getInput(); // returns "north", "south", "west", "east", etc.

   area = moveFromArea(area, direction);

} while(true)
```

where `areas` are defined like this:

```
var areas = {
areaID1: {name: '...', info:'...', image:'...', exits: { north: 'areaID1', south: 'areaID2', ...} }
areaID2: {name: '...', info:'...', image:'...', exits: { north: 'areaID2', south: 'areaID3', ...} }
areaID3: {name: '...', info:'...', image:'...', exits: { north: 'areaID2', south: 'areaID1', ...} },

}
```

where `moveFromArea()` would be defined:

```
function moveFromArea(fromArea, direction) {
    var areaName = fromArea.exits[direction]; 
    if ( !areaName){
        throw "Cannot go there";
    }
    return areas[areaName];
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the help!, I am still in the process of trying out everything, I will get back to you if there is anything else.

Thanks again!